# A linear transformation satisfying $P^2 = P$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that a linear transformation $P \colon V \to V$ of a finite dimensional vector space satisfies $P^2 = P$ if and only if there exists a basis with respect to which $P$ can be written as a block matrix

$$P = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Hence determine the minimal and characteristic polynomials of $P$.

I don't know what to do with this problem at all, so some help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Apply Jordan canonical form.

Comment: This is an 'if and only if' proof.  The 'if' part is straightforward.  Write $P$ in the block matrix form and compute $P^2$ to find that $P^2 = P$.

Comment: I haven't learnt that yet though - I think I need to do it using the definitions of the basis matrix and then applying the P^2 = P rule but I don't know how

Comment: thanks @tylerc0816 but what about the other direction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One direction of the above is easy.

We have $x=Px+(I-P)x$, so we see that $V = {\cal R}P + {\cal R}(I-P)$. If we set $Px+(I-P)y = 0$, then multiplying across by $P$ shows $Px=0$, and multiplying by $I-P$ shows that $(I-P)y = 0$, hence the sum is a direct sum (that is, any $x\in V$ uniquely decomposes into the sum of an element of ${\cal R}P$ and an element of $ {\cal R}(I-P)$). We write this as $V = {\cal R}P 
\oplus {\cal R}(I-P)$.

Now note that ${\cal R}(I-P) = \ker P$, and so $V = \ker P \oplus {\cal R}P $.

Note that both $\ker P $ and $ {\cal R}P $ are $P$ invariant, in fact, $P$ is the zero operator on $\ker P$ and the identity operator on ${\cal R}P $. This gives the block form above.

The characteristic polynomial can be found immediately from the above block form. Since $P = \begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ in the appropriate basis, we have $\lambda I-P = \begin{bmatrix} (\lambda-1)I_r & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda I_k \end{bmatrix}$, and so $\det(\lambda I-P) = (\lambda-1)^r\lambda^k$.

The minimal polynomial can be determined by computing $P(I-P)$.

Comment: what do you mean by RP and R(I-P)

Comment: ${\cal R}P = \{Px | x \in V \}$. That is, the range space.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if $P$ satisfies $P^2=P$, then it is the root of the polynomial $x^2-x=x(x-1)$.
Show that $P$ restricted to ${\rm im\,}P$ is the identity, and that
$$V=\ker P\oplus{\rm im\,}P\,.$$
Then choose arbitrarily bases both in $\ker P$ and in ${\rm im\,}P$.

Here $\ker P$ is the $P$-invariant subspace corresponding to the factor $x$ of the minimal polynomial, and ${\rm im\,} P=\{x:Px=x\}$ is the $P$-invariant subspace corresponding to the factor $x-1$.

Comment: how would I show that?

Comment: Draw. Such a $P$ is also called a (not necessarily orthogonal) *projection*. It projects onto ${\rm im\,}P$ in all directions given by $\ker P$.

Comment: I still don't really understand what's going on here

Comment: Algebraically: if $y\in{\rm im\,}P$ that means $y=Px$ for some $x$, then $Py=P(Px)=P^2x=Px=y$. For a given vector $x\in V$, we have $Px\in{\rm im\,} P$, and $x=Px+(x-Px)$. By the condition, $P(x-Px)=0$. We also need that $\ker P\cap{\rm im\,}P=\{0\}$, and basically that's all.

Comment: okay I follow all of that but how does this then give us the block matrix as required?

Comment: If $e_i$ is the $i$th standard basis vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and $M$ is a matrix, then $Me_i$ gives the $i$th column of the matrix. $\matrix{\quad \\ }$ If you choose basis $b_1,..,b_k$ in ${\rm im\,}P$ and extend it with a basis $b_{k+1},..,b_n$ of $\ker P$, then $Pb_i=b_i$ and $Pb_j=0$ if $i\le k<j$, so $[P]_{\{b_1,..,b_n\} }$ is as wished.